# Salesforce CDP Sandbox extension request

Tags: salesforce-cdp, cdp

Is it possible to extend the duration of the Salesforce CDP sandbox assigned for exercises/labs - For those partners who may be going through the course, the CDP sandbox was provisioned for a month as part of the Partner Learning Camp course Salesforce CDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using CDO/SDO from Partner portal for the CDP environments.

It is better to explore a CDP template and create PBO instead for CDO/SDO if you need longer duration.

Comment: What is pbo and how do I create it

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, the default 30-day expiration is too short. So you can request an extension for your trial period.

Only your Account Executive can extend your org's Trial period. If you've reviewed all relevant documentation and would like to request this limit increase, contact your Account Executive.

For more clarification refer this [extend the salesforce Org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337655&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

As a way of updating, Salesforce is no longer extending the learning CDP Orgs as per their Rules of Engagement:

"CDP Trial Org will only be available for ***30 days*** and will ***not be extendable*** beyond that."